# Subsections as an enumerate

Tags: sectioning, lists, enumerate

I want to have subsections named all the same with a number behind it. The straight forward approach I came up with is this:

```
\section{User Stories}
\subsection*{Userstory 1}
This is story 1
\subsection*{Userstory 2}
This is story 2
```

But I though isn't this possible as a list? So I have tried a few things but none worked. I have just learned the basics of LaTeX, and I want to try some more advanced tricks in LateX, but it won't work. I have tried this and some things very similar to this:

```
\section{User Stories}
\begin{enumerate} [label=\subsection*{Userstory \arabic*}]
    \item This is story 1
    \item This is story 2
\end{enumerate}
```

Is this behaviour even possible to automatically? What is the best approach, for not typing the number and the title every time. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I almost asked this question yesterday but I couldn't think how to phrase it - so thanks martijnn

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325803/4011

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps this would suffice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{userstory}
\def\nextUserStory{\stepcounter{userstory}\subsection*{User Story \theuserstory}}
\begin{document}
\section{User Stories}
\nextUserStory
This is story 1
\nextUserStory
This is story 2
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If I understand Fiona's comment, she would like to have an option to label stories.  EDITED to reflect egreg's comment at Fiona's related question [Cross references to "false" sections (see "subsections as an enumerate")](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176311/cross-references-to-false-sections-see-subsections-as-an-enumerate).  In particular, `\refstepcounter` is needed in lieu of `\stepcounter`, and the `\label` need not be part of the `\nextUserStory` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{userstory}
\newcommand\nextUserStory{\refstepcounter{userstory}\subsection*{User Story \theuserstory}}
\begin{document}
\section{User Stories}
\nextUserStory\label{storyA}
This is story 1
\nextUserStory
This is story 2, which refers to story \ref{storyA}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for :) I have added `\setcounter{userstory}{0}` right after the `\section{User Stories}` just to be sure that the counter is `1`.

Comment: @martijnn2008  I didn't set because the counter would be initialized to zero at the start anyway.  However, if this is used in multiple sections, the counter would indeed need to be reset to zero for each section where used.

Comment: See my edit. :) But I got the point thank you.

Comment: @martijnn2008 See mine. `:^)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if you're still online - what happens when you want to add a `\cref` to such sections? This also happens to be exactly what I want to do but I would like to be able to refer to them elsewhere in the text.

Comment: @FionaSmith Do you mean you want a `\label` in the section header, which can later be accessed by a `\ref`?  I will try to edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, just that. I want to be able to refer to one of these user stories later in the text using code something like `In \cref{US:1} we saw that...` to generate output "In User Story 1 we saw that..."

Comment: @FionaSmith Then please see my edit.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks, that does the job well enough - I'm unlikely to have loads of different versions of this sort of list, so I am sure I can abandon `cleveref` for just one or two cross-references :)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes please see [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176311/cross-references-to-false-sections-see-subsections-as-an-enumerate]