# Cross references to "false" sections (see "subsections as an enumerate")

Tags: sectioning

This question on [Subsections as an enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176263/subsections-as-an-enumerate/) was exactly what I wanted to ask yesterday, and StevenB.Segletes' answer almost does what I want, but it doesn't seem to quite work. I can't really post code in that question to show what I mean, so I felt I ought to start a new question.

What I want to do is generate pseudo-subsections with user-defined titles (In my case I want to write "Case Study 1" etc, just as in the above question. What I also want to do is to be able to refer to these items in the text. Steven's answer looked like it works, but actually the counter doesn't increment, and in fact picks up the section number. Can anyone advise how to get this working?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{casestudy}
\newcommand\nextCaseStudy[1][]{\stepcounter{casestudy}\subsection*{Case Study \thecasestudy#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{Dummy 1}

\section{Dummy 2}

\section{Case Studies}

\nextCaseStudy[\label{cs1}]
Some details
\nextCaseStudy[\label{cs2}]
Some details

\section{My next section}

I now want to refer to something in \ref{cs2}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following output:
[image: output]

Comment: Use `\refstepcounter` instead of `\stepcounter`. No need to use an optional argument; just place `\label` after the command as you would do for `\subsection`.

Comment: My answer at the cited question has been updated to reflect egreg's wisdom.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Fab, I'll go take another look

Comment: Since the original question was updated to accomplish @egreg's wisdom, i vote to close as dupe :-)