# New line after item number in enumeration

Tags: line-breaking, enumerate

I am writing many exercise Sheets for a course in a university. The captions for every Problem is simply: “Problem 1”, “Problem 2” and so on…
Now I came up with the idea, to generate this captions automatically via

```
\begin{enumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\textbf{Problem \arabic{enumi}}}
\setlength{\itemindent}{32pt}
\item Lorem ipsum…
\end{enumerate}
```

But my problem now is that “Lorem ipsum…” is not in a new line under the generated caption. `\\` and `\newline` do not work. Has anybody an idea to handle this issue?

Comment: `\let\olditem\item \def\item{\olditem\leavevmode\par}`

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176263/subsections-as-an-enumerate maybe this is a good idea? Else you could try `\item ~\\ Lorem`

Comment: Thanks for the Link. Now I am using: \newcounter{problems}
\def\Problem{\stepcounter{problems}\vspace{2em}\textbf{Problem \arabic{problems}}\\\\ }

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) you can define a custom alignment of the label so that it takes the full line width:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}

\SetLabelAlign{LeftAlignFullWidth}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth+\labelwidth\relax][l]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries Problem \arabic*}, align=LeftAlignFullWidth]
\item  Lorem ipsum one
\item  Lorem ipsum two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```