# Enumerated list in subsubsection style

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

How can I define a list environment using a package like enumitem such that it reproduces the same output as the following code but with the syntax of an enumerated list:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Item 1}
\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection*{Item 2}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{Item 3}
\lipsum[3]

%% The following syntax should produce the same as above.

% \begin{mylist}
%   \item 
%     \lipsum[1]
%   \item 
%     \lipsum[2]
%   \item 
%     \lipsum[3]
% \end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Shall `Item 1` etc. be printed as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly as in the output of the posted example.

Comment: Using `\subsubsection*` is easier then, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You mean something like this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176265/4011

Comment: Yes, pretty much like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possibility

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[mylist]{
    label=\bfseries Item \arabic*,
    labelwidth=\widthof{last-item},
    leftmargin=!,
    align=left,
    itemindent=1.8cm,
    itemsep=10pt
}

\newcommand{\myitem}{\item~\\[6pt]}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Item 1}
\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection*{Item 2}
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection*{Item 3}
\lipsum[3]

%% The following syntax should produce the same as above.


 \begin{mylist}
   \myitem
     \lipsum[1]
   \myitem 
     \lipsum[2]
   \myitem 
     \lipsum[3]
 \end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I had to redefine `\item` too so to send the item text to a new line.

```
labelwidth=\widthof{last-item},
leftmargin=!,
align=left,
```

are for setting the label next to the margin. To automatically calculate the largest label width the package `calc` is needed.

```
itemindent=1.8cm,
```

is for removing the indent of the item text (this is the only value I wasn't able to compute automatically but should be fixed, so not a big deal)

```
itemsep=10pt
```

sets the vertical space between items

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item~\\[6pt]}
```

sends the item text to a newline with a vertical space of 6pt from the label.

Comment: Actually you did not redefine `\item`, you wrapped in another macro ;-) Hopefully `\myitem[...]` is never requested ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer oh yes, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2):

A very simple code, which lets you use the usual `\item` command:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{1}

\setlist[mylist]{label=\raisebox{0pt}[4ex][3ex]{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\bfseries Item \arabic*}}, wide = 0pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{mylist}
   \item
     \lipsum[1]
   \item
     \lipsum[2]
   \item
     \lipsum[3]
 \end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]